# Replace two for loops using vectorization?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a function `f(x,y) = abs(cos(x+3) * sin(y+2))` that I need to sum up using two for loops. Note: the real function is more complex, this is a toy version of it for the purposes of the question.

```
f = @(x,y) abs(cos(x+3) * sin(y+2));

tot = 0;
for m=1:100
    for n=1:100
        tot = tot + f(m,n);
    end
end

disp(tot)

Output: 4.026314876227891e+03
```

How can I vectorize this code to get rid of the for loops and make it faster?

Answer (score 2):

```
[n,m]=meshgrid(1:100,1:100);
tot=sum(f(m,n),'all')
```

However I am not sure this is any faster, you can time it. Matlab is quite fast in loops, the old truth about it being slower when you loop is outdated by 5 years or so. Most of the times the JIT compiler will find the fastest way to run it. This is one of the cases where your toy problem may hid the actual problem, as the JIT may find this toy problem easier to speed up, but not your real one, or vice versa.

You will need to time.

Comment: To add a detail to this solution: For the vectorization to work, the function `f` must be properly implemented. The definition from OP would result in expensive matrix-matrix multiplications (with undesired results), while the actual desired computation uses point-wise multiplication: `f = @(x,y) abs(cos(x+3) .* sin(y+2));`